# Server application hangs Java socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, connection

My application keeps loading (circle cursor). Here is my code

```
public class ControllerW {

@FXML
private Label statusLbl, timeLbl, textLbl;
@FXML
private Button exitBtn, linkBtn;

private ServerSocket serverSckt;
private Socket clientSckt;
DataInputStream dis;
String text;

@FXML
private void exit() {
    System.exit(0);
}

@FXML
private void linkAndroid() {
    try {
        serverSckt = new ServerSocket(5678);
        statusLbl.setText("Server started");
        clientSckt = serverSckt.accept();
        statusLbl.setText("client connected successfully");
        dis = new DataInputStream(clientSckt.getInputStream());
        text = dis.toString();
        textLbl.setText(text);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        statusLbl.setText("No connection on port 5678");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I am new to socket programming, could someone please help me if there is anything wrong with my code

Comment: Could you elaborate a little about "My application keeps loading" and how you call `linkAndroid()` and if you connect any device during that time. Because on the first glance eveything looks just fine.

Comment: `statusLbl.setText("Server started");` based upon the posted code you will get a null pointer exception here

Comment: I have a button called (linkBtn) which starts the server and waits until someone connects. After pressing it, it just keeps on loading and eventually the not responding window pops up when u click on it. And no I do not get any errors on my console.

Comment: I haven't made the client application yet (which will be on the android device)

Comment: Is your UI running in a dedicated Thread? If not a possible cause for that behaviour could be [`ServerSocket#accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--) because of it beeing a **blocking** operation until a connection has been established.

Comment: Nope, don't know. How do I do that? btw i'm using javafx for my UI

Answer (score 2):

Your application is stopping to respond because it's not threaded. Without multithreading your application will 'stop' the moment you click your "link" button because the call to [`ServerSocket#accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--).

The reason for that is the **blocking** nature of the `accept` method. Until another socket connects the `ServerSocket` is waiting and keeps his current thread 'suspended'. Think of it as an inner while loop similiar to this:

```
while(!isConnected())
{
    // check if there is a new request
}
```

Imagine no client would ever connect. How would this loop ever stop? Never.

A possible workaround is to either thread the entire UI part or 'data model' part.

My prefered way is to create a custom class which only handles the `ServerSocket#accept` method and delegates incoming connections to another thread which takes care of the rest. I do that to keep my server accessible at any time which might not be the best approach for your problem.

This is how my helper class commonly looks like:

**ClientAccepter.java:**

```
public class ClientAccepter
    implements Runnable
{
  // the ServerSocket
  private final ServerSocket server;
  // ExecutorServices ease the pain of threading your application quite a lot
  private final ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  
  private boolean isAlive = true;

  public ClientAccepter( ServerSocket server )
  {
    this.server = server;
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    //This is where you specify your desired behaviour.
    //Example:
    while ( isAlive )
    {
      try
      {
        es.execute( new ClientHandler( server.accept() ) );
      }
      catch ( IOException e )
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The call to such a class could look like this:

**Server.java:**

```
public class Server
{
  //ExecutorServices are the best and easy to use.
  private static ExecutorService serverThreader = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    try
    {
      serverThreader.execute( new ClientAccepter( new ServerSocket( 8080 ) ) );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
     //further exception handling.
    }
  }
}
```

To be fair this might not be the best approach but it's my preferred way of handling blocking operations. You should consider working through the [orcale concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) and definitly take a look at [`ExecutorServices`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) because they are an incredible framework to handle threadpools with ease.

---

Also specificly for JavaFX there is a [concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).

Answer (score 0):

First you run the socket with the GUI/JFX thread. so `accept()` will block it (UI won't be responsible, dat circle you know).

You need to run the IO/socket with another thread. but beware, you need to change the UI stuffs with UI thread. (for example `textLbl.setText(text);` may fail if is called from another thread directly)

Also this line `text = dis.toString();` is nonsense, you supposed to get a string sent from client? So use(recommended) `readLine()` method from `BufferedReader` instead of `DataInputStream`. (`readUTF` may work from `DataInputStream` too).

Comment: Is this why I'm getting a nullpointerxception when trying to settext of the label from a different thread? I've been trying to figure out how to access the label of the controller from the thread which handles the connection.

Comment: It should not be a null point exception, but the set text op could be ignored, or throws another exception. if you get null point ex, so you have to check if the variable is correctly initialized. in catch when you print the stack trace, check to see which line cause this error. so simple to fix. keep going on good work.